# Symfony2 LessPHP works fine in dev environment but not in prod

Tags: symfony, lessphp

I have a website under Symfony2 using LessPHP. In dev environment everything works fine.
When I hit `http://mylocalsite/app_dev.php/` the browser reaches `http://mylocalsite/app_dev.php/css/XXXX_myFile_1.css`.

But when I hit `http://mylocalsite/` the browser tries to reach `http://mylocalsite/css/XXXX_myFile_1.css` and gets a 404 error.

prod.log contains no more than this

```
[2014-01-24 12:08:46] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /css/XXXX_myFile_1.css"" at /the/path
```

The config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        lessphp:
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            # Formatter options: compressed, lessjs, classic
            formatter: "compressed"
            preserve_comments: false
```

The twig template

```
{% stylesheets '@ProjectMyBundle/Resources/less/myFile.less' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

**EDIT**

I did `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` which gave me a `web/css/XXXX.css` file. But the browser is still looking for a file called `XXXX_myFile_1.css`.

I tried to set the output like this

```
{% stylesheets output='css/myFile.css'
    '@ProjectMyBundle/Resources/less/myFile.less' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Executed `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` another time which gave me a `web/css/myFile.css` file. But now the browser is looking for a file called `myFile_myFile_1.css`.

**ANSWER**

`use_controller` must be set to **true** in the config.yml file.

Thanks

Comment: Did you dump the assets with `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`?

Comment: I did but I still 404 error. I edited the post.

Comment: Do you have the assetic setting `use_controller` set to true in your `config.yml` or `config_prod.yml`?

Comment: You should add your bundle in the `bundles` array if you have assets that should be handled by assetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dump the assets (= assetic will combine all these assets into one big file). On the dev environment the file is served through the main controller and is generated dynamically. When you deploy an app, you should dump the assets using

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

So as to generate these files physically on the file system. [Read more in the Symfony docs.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment)